# save large chunk of JSON without cookies

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing an HTML/JavaScript program that gives me a JSON object as a string.

I want to save that string as a cookie, but the string is too large to be saved as a cookie.

How can this JSON string be saved without cookies?

Comment: What sort of browser compatibility are you looking for? I ask because there is a method using HTML 5 but only newer ones can use it.

Comment: A cookie can only hold 4K of data.  How large is this JSON object?

Comment: I'm going to downvote this if the OP doesn't supply the necessary information for one to actually answer.  For what duration does the JSON needs to be saved?  Across pages?  Across domains?  How large is it?  Does it have to work in older browsers that don't have HTML5 local storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on browser coverage, you can use HTML [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage) object. Or flash cookies as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to stick around when you leave the page?  If not, just store it in a javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

The two sort of mainstream ways to do this are to store it in local or server side databases:

So server side you can look at SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.
Client side you can look at Local Storage: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Save it in the session or cache it?

We need to know more information. What framework are you using? Is the only technology you want to use HTML/Javascript?